# Updating a Specific Item in a List

Tags: list, elm

Given an elm list like:

```
twoDimensionalList =
    [ [ 'U', 'U', ' ' ]
    , [ ' ', ' ', ' ' ]
    , [ ' ', ' ', ' ' ]
    ]
```

How can I update the `' '` in the first row with `'U'` within an Elm List? I do not want to use an array I want to figure out how to do this with a List.  I've already done the convert List to array and use set. I'm trying to learn how I'd update at a certain element in a list this time.

I started to think about how I might do this but just can't get there:

```
row1 =
   take 0 twoDimensionalList

row1Updated =
   indexedMap \i row1 -> if i == 2 then --somehow update this item in the map with 'U'
```

Answer (score 3):

For this particular scenario, I would just pattern match on the list, bind the parts I want to preserve to variables, then reconstruct it with my replacement value:

```
case twoDimensionalList of
    [ a, b, _ ] :: tail ->
        [ a, b, 'U' ] :: tail

    _ ->
        twoDimensionalList
```

Basically, the `::` operator (called "cons") will match or bind the first element (called "head") on the left of it, and the rest of the list (the "tail") on the right. So `"a" :: ["b", "c"]` will match the list `["a", "b", "c"]`.

The list literal syntax (`[...]`) in a pattern will match a list of exactly that size. So the `[a, b, _] :: tail` will match a list with the first ("head") element itself being a three-element list where the first two elements are bound to the variables `a` and `b` and the third element, which we're going to replace, is ignored. The rest of the outer list is then bound to `tail`.

The list is then reconstructed using pretty much the same syntax. The list literal syntax I'm sure you're familiar with, and the cons operator (`::`) works similarly to its pattern form, adding the element on the left to the list on the right, e.g. `"a" :: ["b", "c"]` will return the list `["a", "b", "c"]`

Comment: wow this got me lost I haven't used any of that before such as pattern matching, of syntax, etc.

Comment: Hmm, looks like the Elm guide glosses over that part. There's a bit about it here though: https://gist.github.com/yang-wei/4f563fbf81ff843e8b1e#list. And here: https://elmprogramming.com/pattern-matching.html

Comment: the docs glance over a lot :).  Everyone tells you Elm is simple but it's not if you're new to an ML lang and Elm.

Comment: It _IS_ simple compared to most other ML languages, but still glosses over quite a few useful (as opposed to "strictly necessary") concepts :) I've fleshed out the answer a bit. Hope that helps!